# How to solve this weird wireless problem in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I can't event turn on the wireless button

My wireless card is Atheros AR9287

[image: Atheros AR9287]

I use lshow to check the status of wireless card, logic name is wlp3s0, it's disabled.

[image: Network disabled - Atheros AR9287]

[image: Network options]

I download some drivers from [this website](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/download), but I get errors when I run `make`, I really need help.

this is after I run `rfkill list` and `rfkill unblock all`, still doesn't work
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34kRx.png)

Comment: It may be you have to enter your machine's BIOS (UEFI) and enable it there. The OS (Ubuntu) can't overrule a hardware block.  (*this may not be the issue, some machines hardware-block stop the OS from even seeing the hardware*).   For us the help with the `make` we'd need your actual error, but I suspect you have a machine specific problem stopping like a BIOS setting disabling wireless.

Comment: there's no such option in BIOS, make error: lib-average.c error implicit declaration of function ACCESS_ONCE

Comment: Include all essential information in your question. Linking to information is OK if not essential to solve the issue, but essential information should be available in the post itself.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for 'rfkill list`

Answer (score 0):

1st, try running `sudo service network-manager restart`. This will restart the network manager.

Then, run `sudo rfkill unblock all`, which will re-enable the wireless card in case you accidentally disabled it like I did a few months ago in Linux Mint. ([Source](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=140356#p745590))

Comment: I tried, still doesn't work

Comment: @PeterZhang Then maybe your card is not entirely compatible with 16.04 or it's faulty. Try upgrading to 18.04 instead. Newer versions have better support.